# React npm start 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost on windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, hosts

So i am trying to launch my react application using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Here is what i tried:

1. in scripts i put the following for start

   ```
   "start": "set HOST=127.0.0.1 && react-scripts start"
   ```

   This yields following error:

   ```
   Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 127.0.0.1
   If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
   Learn more here: 
   node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26)
   Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1493:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:17) {
   errno: -3008,
   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
   hostname: '127.0.0.1 '
   ```

I also tried updating my hosts file to have following line:
localhost 127.0.0.1

Note that i can launch 127.0.0.1 in launch.json but that only applies to when i am debugging

Comment: Why are you trying to use an IP address as a host name? what's the point?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I am trying to start up application as 127.0.0.1:3000 instead of default localhost:3000 because some of the software i am working with fails for localhost but works for 127.0.0.1. I can manually change it when it runs but i should be able to do this dynamically

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is an IP and localhost is a name for this IP, your software should be able to access the app that is running on localhost via 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: I understand that but like i said before the software doesn't like localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally figured this out. Created a file called ".env.local" (mind the beginning .) containing following:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Comment: This method works great with custom domain too - like if you wanted to simulate that you are on subdomain of your final page (eg local.mydomain.com). You need to edit hosts file. For any question why - because of integration. If you want to develop integration with external service you often want to work on given subdomain for security reason (like server will reply only for **.myDomain.com requests).

Answer (score 0):

For those who this answer (Maxqueue) does not work try :

- Renaming the file .env.local (add the dot)
- run yarn or npm one more time

worked for me !